# Passing object to sliding tabs fragment on create

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, slidingmenu

I am trying to pass an object that is retrieved and created during my main activities on create method to one of the fragments of my sliding tabs layout.

Since this object is created over a network connection my plan was to receive the data during the creation of the Main Activity then pass the resulting object to my fragments. However this seems easier said than done. The resulting object will then get passed to a recycler view in the Forecast fragment.

I have read various methods including implementing the parcelable interface on my model object, storing it as a bundle and trying to send it over to the fragment. However it always came up null. I believe this was due to me creating a new fragment in memory and not passing the bundle to the fragment that was displayed. I also don't have any ID's for the fragments so locating them by ID isn't possible, at least to my knowledge.

If anyone could point me in the right direction Id be greatly appreciative.

**Main Activity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MAIN ACTIVITY";
@Bind(R.id.toolBar) Toolbar mToolbar;
@Bind(R.id.viewPager) ViewPager mViewPager;
@Bind(R.id.tabLayout) SlidingTabLayout mTabLayout;

private ViewPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private String mForecastsTabName = "Forecasts";
private String mAlertsTabName = "Alerts";
private String mTabTitles[] = {mForecastsTabName, mAlertsTabName};
private  int mNumberOfTabs = 2;
private Forecast[] mForecasts;
private JsonParser mJsonParser = new JsonParser();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    setupSlidingTabs();
}

private void setupSlidingTabs() {
    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mTabTitles, mNumberOfTabs);

    // Assigning the ViewPages View and setting the adapter
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Assigning the Sliding Tab Layout View
    mTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width
    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    mTabLayout.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorAccent);
        }
    });

    mTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
}
```

**Forecast Fragment.java**

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String FORECAST_KEY = "FORECAST_KEY";
private static final String TAG = "FRAGMENT";
private Forecast[] mForecasts;

@Bind(R.id.recyclerView) RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
@Bind(R.id.emptyView) TextView mEmptyView;
@Bind(R.id.locationButton) Button mLocationButton;

public static ForecastFragment newInstance(Forecast[] forecasts) {
    ForecastFragment fragment = new ForecastFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelableArray(FORECAST_KEY, forecasts);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Initialize dataset, this data would usually come from a local content provider or
    // remote server.
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.forecast_tab_fragment, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    displayEmptyViewIfNoData();

    ForecastAdapter adapter = new ForecastAdapter(getActivity(), mForecasts);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    return view;
}


private void displayEmptyViewIfNoData() {
    if (mForecasts == null || mForecasts.length < 1) {
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLocationButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mLocationButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@OnClick(R.id.locationButton)
public void selectLocations(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LocationSelectionActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ActivityConstants.CALLING_ACTIVITY, ActivityConstants.FORECAST_ACTIVITY);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

**ViewPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
// This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
String mTitles[];
// Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created
int mNumberOfTabs;
SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String titles[], int numberOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    mTitles = titles;
    mNumberOfTabs = numberOfTabs;
}

//This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        ForecastFragment forecastFragment = new ForecastFragment();
        return forecastFragment;
    }
    else if (position == 1) {
        AlertFragment alertFragment = new AlertFragment();
        return alertFragment;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    registeredFragments.remove(position);
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}

public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
    return registeredFragments.get(position);
}

// This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mTitles[position];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumberOfTabs;
}
```

}

**Forecast_tab_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/ColorPrimaryLight">

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"/>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/emptyView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/empty_forecast_message"
       android:textColor="@color/ColorTextPrimary"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:visibility="gone"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="115dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/locationButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:textColor="@color/ColorTextPrimary"
    android:text="@string/add_forecast_button"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emptyView"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do this code below, you can hand the data to your fragment.

In your Activity, call below, when the data is ready:

```
mAdapter.getFragment(index).setData(dataObject);
```

or

```
mAdapter.getFragment(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()).setData(dataObject);
```

Your FragmentPagerAdater should be like this:

```
class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        SparseArray<App4StoreBaseSubFragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<App4StoreBaseSubFragment>();
        public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        App4StoreBaseSubFragment fragment = (App4StoreBaseSubFragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        registeredFragments.remove(position);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

        public ForecastFragment getFragment(int position){
            return registeredFragments.get(position);
        }

    }
```

Your Fragment should be like this:

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {
         public void setData(Forecast forecast){
              //write code here to change UI
         }
    }
```

Comment: When I call this in my MainActivity.java onCreate method after i setup the adapter and viewpager I get a null pointer exception. It seems to be that the Fragment is not created yet. Any ideas on what to do?  Here is the code I use to set the data `ForecastFragment fragment = (ForecastFragment) mAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.setData(mForecasts);
        }`

Comment: I think it is better for you to get the current Fragment by using Interface. When your fragment starts, your fragment can call a method of the activity.  you have to make sure your Fragment is loaded and try to access it.

Comment: In short, call a function of the activity when the OnCreate started in the Fragment.